# determining the parameters of a function using disassembler

Tags: c, android-ndk, disassembly

I've got an unofficial header for a c library that i'm using for an android project. The library comes with versions for the classical architectures arm and x86 both with 64 and 32 bit. 
I'm trying to determine if the number and type of parameters in one function are correct: with hopper disassembler, i can see pseudo c code derived from that function, and hopper gives different number of parameters for different architectures. I'm pretty convinced that the header is the same for the different architectures though. So how to determine the correct number of parameters?

Example:

arm64:

```
int theFunction(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    saved_fp = r29;
    stack[-56] = r30;
    r31 = r31 + 0xffffffffffffffc0;
    r29 = &saved_fp;
    saved_regs_10 = r19;
    stack[-40] = r20;
    saved_regs_30 = r23;
    saved_regs_20 = r21;
    stack[-24] = r22;
    r22 = arg0;
    r21 = arg1;
    r20 = arg2;
    r23 = arg3;
    r5 = **0x5afc0;
```

arm32:

```
int theFunction(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    stack[-4] = r4;
    stack[-8] = r5;
    stack[-12] = r6;
    stack[-16] = r7;
    stack[-20] = r8;
    stack[-24] = lr;
    sp = sp - 0x20;
    r12 = **0x46ef4;
    r6 = r0;
    r5 = r1;
    r7 = r2;
    r8 = r3;
    if (r12 != 0x0) {
```

x86:

```
int theFunction(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4, int arg5, int arg6, int arg7, int arg8, int arg9, int arg10, int arg11, int arg12, int arg13, int arg14) {
    var_60 = arg14;
    var_48 = arg11;
    var_44 = arg10;
    var_40 = arg9;
    var_36 = arg8;
    var_32 = arg7;
    var_28 = arg6;
    var_24 = arg5;
    var_20 = arg4;
    var_16 = arg3;
    var_12 = arg2;
    var_8 = arg1;
    var_4 = arg0;
    var_8 = edi;
    var_C = esi;
    esp = esp - 0xc;
    var_10 = ebx;
    eax = sub_267b();
    ebx = ebx + 0x432ab;
    esp = &var_3C;
    esi = *(ebx - 0x24);
    edi = arg12;
    ebp = arg13;
    eax = *esi;
```

x86_64:

```
int theFunction(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    rdx = arg2;
    rsi = arg1;
    rdi = arg0;
    stack[-8] = r14;
    r14 = arg3;
    stack[-16] = r13;
    LODWORD(r13) = LODWORD(rdx);
    stack[-24] = r12;
    LODWORD(r12) = LODWORD(rsi);
    stack[-32] = rbp;
    rsp = rsp - 0x28;
    stack[-40] = rbx;
    rbx = rdi;
    r9 = **qword_56e50;
```

funnily, the parameters on the Java api public api are 3, so maybe that is the right number...

Another example:

arm64:

```
int anotherFunction(int arg0) {
    saved_fp = r29;
    stack[-24] = r30;
    r31 = r31 + 0xffffffffffffffe0;
    r29 = &saved_fp;
    saved_regs_10 = r19;
    stack[-8] = r20;
    r20 = arg0;
    r3 = **0x5afc0;
    if (r3 != 0x0) {
```

arm32:

```
int anotherFunction(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    r2 = arg2;
    r1 = arg1;
    stack[-4] = arg3;
    stack[-8] = r4;
    stack[-12] = r5;
    sp = sp - 0x10;
    stack[-16] = lr;
    r5 = arg0;
    r3 = **0x46ef4;
    if (r3 != 0x0) {
```

Comment: The OS platform not the architecture defines different ABIs. Arguments are not always passed on the stack, but in registers.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about the Java side. That strongly suggests that the function in question is a native (JNI) method of a Java class.

If there are 3 parameters on the Java side, that means the function takes 5 parameters on the C side. The JNI convention specifies the two first parameters to be the `JNIEnv* env, jobject self`. The first one is the set of points into the JNI API functions, the second one is the class object pointer for static functions, `this` object pointer for member function.